# ERROR: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-redux

I'm new to react and I've been playing around with it the past few days. Whenever I try to run this simple code below it keeps giving me the error.

**"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."**

I'm not sure why, can anybody please help me? Thank you in advance.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';



export default class State1 extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = { value: "llll" };
  }

  change() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({value:"eeee"});
    },3000);
  }

  change2() {
      this.setState({value:"eeee"});
  }
  
  render() {
    {this.change2()};
    return (
      <div > {this.state.value} </div >
    ) 
  }


}
```

Comment: remove setState from `change2` method it will work.

Comment: @MayankShukla Why is that the change() function that uses setTimeout() doesnt cause a infinite loop like function change2() does?

Comment: because you are not using that function anywhere, also if you execute that function on click of button or in correct place it will not cause infinite loop, setState should not be called directly inside render method.

Answer (score 7):

Every time you invoke `setState()`, Your component will call the `render` method to reflect the change in state, which will then invoke `change2()`, thus causing an endless loop.

Comment: Ohhh okay, that makes so much sense, thank you!!!! So how exactly would I use this.SetState() in react.js without a click event or setTimeout? Those two scenarios are the two I have gotten to work for me.

Comment: Also, Why is that the change() function that uses setTimeout() doesnt cause a infinite loop like function change2() does?

Comment: `change()` is still causing an infinite loop, but at a slower rate (A `setState` will occur every 3 seconds, causing a re-render). You would usually use `setState` in response to a user interaction or api response.

Comment: all right, so is it save to say I would only use state instead of props when I'm waiting for some sort of a event listener/api response? Other than that, in most cases I would use Props?

Comment: last question lol, you somewhat addressed it already but why is that when I use a click listener for this.setState, it doesnt cause a infinite loop? Is it a similar situation like the SetTimeout?

Comment: If you look at your `render()` above, you'll see that it will invoke `this.change2()`. The difference with a click handler is that you're not invoking it on render. You only invoke it when the `onClick` event fires. Sure, when you click the element, the render method will run, but it's not going to fire the click event again.

Comment: I understand it now, you made my life so much easier. Thank you once again :)